# Recording website load times?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, firefox, testing, firebug

I am trying to record the time it takes to load my website on an average (say 10 runs) from various locations in the world. For this, I was thinking of using a list of proxies to achieve this and am not sure this is the perfect way of doing this.

1. Is there a Firefox add-on that lets me time this perhaps using Firebug itself?
2. Is there an alternate way of running this test?

Any tips from the testing community would be awesome.

Comment: Have you checked out [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)?

Comment: @CD Sanchez: Looks very interesting. I'll check it out now... Thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with unit-testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "Net" tab in Firebug
- Google PageSpeed
- Yahoo YSlow

You can also add a snippet of JavaScript to your pages and your clients can report their page render speed
http://blog.yottaa.com/2010/10/how-to-measure-page-load-time-with-google-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Page Speed for Firefox](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did timings using the unix/linux command 'wget' (or 'curl'). What I would do was:

```
time wget 'hxxp://mycoolwebsite.com' > index.html
time curl 'hxxp://mycoolwebsite.com' > index.html
```

I did this for a mostly text-based web server that performed an action in php before returning a value. There are options to specify if you get the images too ( i think).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know how to download all included files in a html file as well using curl?

Comment: Not only with the curl utility - you'd have to sort the output and then curl the sorted list of includes (what format is this? .html?) (then do it again! until there's no more include files if I understand what you mean).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't recommend [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) more.  While it doesn't check performance "around the world", it does make guesses based on typical latency.  Plus, you get the actual load time (don't confuse this with render time) as done in an actual browser.  Lots of web-based tools will download all the files for your page, but due to scripting and other things, they will miss tons.  Fiddler catches everything.

Answer (score 0):

there is also [internetsupervision](http://internetsupervision.com/scripts/urlcheck/check.aspx?lan=en-US&checkurl=stackoverflow.com&email=), though I'm not sure how accurate it *really* is.

Answer (score 0):

[pingdom.com](http://www.pingdom.com/) has a freemium solution for this. One site for free, more sites will cost you.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an external service for this. The service may have a Firefox plugin you can use, but ultimately you want to have your queries run from multiple controlled testing servers that are built to test your load in isolation from other variables.